# Textbox cannot be set with iframe tags

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, iframe, web

I am trying to display a textbox on UI where the value of the textbox is initialized to the following.

Here is my code.

```
...
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTest" runat="server" Visible="true" />
...
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtTest.Text = "<iframe width=\"100%\" height=\"300\" src=\"//jsfiddle.net/vhyseni/rj0tv76x/embedded/\" allowfullscreen=\"allowfullscreen\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe>"
}
```

However the textbox is empty on page load. If I misspell iframe or use some other text (even e.g. "hello") the textbox is initialized correctly. Is there some issue with asp textbox that makes this string invalid?

Comment: Can you get a [mcve]?

Comment: It fills the textbox just fine (after I put `;` at the end)

Answer (score 0):

You have to encode your HTML before asigning it to txtTest.Text

`txtTest.Text = Server.HtmlEncode("you html");`